# How many blowups do we need to make a pencil base point free?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, blowup, projective-varieties

Let $\Bbb{P}^2$ be the projective plane over $\Bbb{C}$.

Take a pencil of curves of degree $d$ on $\Bbb{P}^2$ given by a dominant rational map $\phi:\Bbb{P}^2\dashrightarrow \Bbb{P}^1$.

The pencil has $d^2$ base points, possibly infinitely near. If $p:S\to\Bbb{P}^2$ is the blow up at all $d^2$ base points, then $\phi\circ p:S\to\Bbb{P}^1$ is a base point free pencil on $S$.

My question is: do we always have to blow up $d^2$ times in order to get a base point free pencil?

I agree this is necessary when the $d^2$ base points are not infinitely near. But if one of the base points has many infinitely near it, then this is not clear to me.

Comment: Have you worked out any particularly ornery examples, like the pencil spanned by some $F$ and $G$ with the property that their union $FG=0$ has a higher order tacnode or something like that?

Comment: Yes, at first I was worried about this tacnode business, which I'm totally not familiar with. But earlier today I came across a simpler example: let $F=y^2z-x^3$ and $G=x^2z-y^3$. They intersect at $P:=(0:0:1)$, which is a sigularity for both. Since they have no common tangent at $P$, we get $m_P(F\cap G)=4$. If we blow up only once at $P$, we already separate $F,G$ above $P$. Then if we blowup the other five base points (therefore six blowups in total), we get a base point free pencil.

Comment: Right? @TabesBridges

Comment: This is a little tricky, but yes, I think this works. All of the curves in the initial pencil have two-dimensional tangent space at $P$, but upon blowing up the proper transforms $\tilde F$ and $\tilde G$ have distinct intersections with the exceptional divisor $E$, so $\widetilde{sF + tG}$ will have distinct intersection with $E$ for distinct $(s:t)$. The one thing to keep in mind is that I *think* all of the curves in the base point free pencil will be tangent to $E$ since $\tilde F$ and $\tilde G$ are, so...

Comment: ...if that causes issues of some kind in your particular problem, you may need to blow up $\tilde F \cap E$ and $\tilde G \cap E$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\phi\colon \mathbb{P}^2\dashrightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$ be a rational map given by a pencil of curves of degree $d$. Then, denoting by $p_1,\ldots,p_r$ the base-points of the system, including infinitely near, you get $d^2=\sum_{i=1}^r m_i^2$, where $m_i$ is the multiplicity at the point $p_i$. If $r=d^2$, then $m_1=\ldots=m_r=1$, but in general you might have less than $d^2$ base-points.

To solve the indeterminacies of $\phi$ you need to blow-up ALL base-points, including infinitely near. This is in fact the definition of a base-point: a point where the rational map (or the one obtained after blowing-up firstly some other points if your point is infinitely near) is not defined.

Taking examples with tacnodes or any kind of singularities just change the position of the base-points and their multiplicities.

In the example $F=x^2z-y^3$, $G=y^2z-x^3$,you can parametrise the curve $F=0$ by choosing $x=u^3,y=vu^2,z=v^3$. This gives a birational morphism from $\mathbb{P}^1$ to the singular cubic $\{F=0\}$. Replacing in $G$ gives $u^4(v^5-u^5)$. Hence you get $6$ distinct points, namely $[0:0:1]$ and five distinct other points. The intersection multiplicity at $[0:0:1]$ is $4$, as you have $u^4$. This corresponds to the product of the multiplicities $4=2\cdot 2$, as you do not have any tangent direction. In the above notation it then gives $d=3$, $m_1=2, m_2=\cdots=m_6=1$, so you indeed get only $6$ base-points.

Comment: Thanks, Jeremy! What you're saying is perfectly reasonable to me, but I'm still trying to figure out what's going on with the specific example I discussed with Tabes Bridges

Comment: Namely, the pencil of cubics defined by $F:=x^2z-y^3$ and by $G:=y^2z-x^3$. The cubics $F,G$ are singular at $P:=(0:0:1)$ with different tangent directions at it. If we blow up only once at $P$, doesn't it resolve the indeterminacy at $P$?

Comment: @rmdmc89 You are welcome. I've given some explananation for the example you give. It is indeed two cubics with a point of multiplicity $2$ so the pencil has multiplicity $2$ at the point. As there is no common tangent, there is no infinitely near point. You get in this case only $6$ base-points.

Comment: By the way, I think you meant $d^2=\sum_{i=1}^rm_i$ instead of $d^2=\sum_{i=1}^rm_i^2$, right? I understand $m_i$ as $m_{p_i}(F\cap G)$ by definition, so that $\sum_im_i=F\cdot G=d^2$.

Comment: No, I meant $d^2-\sum_{i=1}^r m_i^2$, where I take for $m_i$ the multiplicity of a member of the pencil at the point $p_i$. If you consider the intersection multiplicity, your formula also works, but you do not see infinitely near points. The intersection multiplicity $m_p(F\cap G)$ is equal to the sum of $m_q(F)\cdot m_q(G)$ when $q$ ranges over all points infinitely near to $p$. Replacing $F,G$ by $aF+bG$ and $cF+dG$ for $a,b,c,d$ general enough, you get $m_q(F)=m_q(G)$ for each point $q$.

Comment: Oh, I see... that's a very important distinction. So if the curves $F,G$ were both smooth, then the multiplicity of a member of the pencil at $p_i$ would be exactly $m_{p_i}(F\cap G)$, right?

Comment: If the curves are both smooth, then $m_q(F)=m_q(G)=1$ for each point $q$, so the multiplicity of a member of the pencil at $p_i$ is $1$. But this does not mean that $m_{p_i}(F\cap G)$ is $1$, this can be arbitrary large, it depends on how many infinitely near points you get (tangency)